# Why is my new altcoin trying to connect to peers and sees almost 200k blocks remaining?

Tags: blockchain, block, nodes, blackcoin

I downloaded and forked the Blackcoin source code. I changed all of the references to BlackCoin, changed the pszTimestamp string along with the current Unix timestamp. Then, I successfully mined the genesis block and put it, along with the merkle hash and the nNonce into the source code and recompiled.

My wallet loads up just fine. The problem is, it says it ha 16 active connections to the network and sees 193k blocks it needs to download. In the debug.log file, theses are all orphan blocks. Also in the debug.log file, it is showing that it is trying to connect to what I assume are built in nodes somewhere in the BlackCoin source code. I cannot find these for the life of me.

How can I change this so that my coin knows the correct blockchain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every coin has some defined set of seed servers it can to connect to in order to build up the initial list of peers.

See:

static const char *strDNSSeed

in

https://github.com/ralphtheninja/blackcoin/blob/master/src/net.cpp

Comment: Got it, thanks! I commented out the dns seeds in the original source and compiled my wallet. I suppose I either need to host a node and add it into the .conf file, or use bitcoin-seeder and get a vps server.